# Can I redirect_to using the `PUT` verb in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Basically I want to redirect to a `PUT` controller action using the `redirect_to` method but it just wants to use the `GET` verb. Is there a way to specify the HTTP verb in the `redirect_to`?

The route is defined as in **rake routes**

```
resume_user PUT    /users/:id/resume(.:format)  users#resume
```

and I have used all of the following with the same result `No route matches [GET] "/users/5/resume"`

- redirect_to resume_user_url(@user)
- redirect_to action: 'resume', controller: 'users', id: @user.id
- redirect_to action: 'resume', controller: 'users', method: 'put', id: @user.id

I might be using it wrong, in which case, any suggestions?
Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) does not allow for this. A redirect with status 307 forbids the browser from changing the request method when following the redirect but there is no mechanism for requesting a particular method be used.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I totally forgot to look at the HTTP spec, thought it was a Rails issue. Time to re-evaluate the flow.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but It not easy to find the answer so...
If you came from an get or post request, you can change the method adding status: 303

```
 redirect_to resume_user_path(@user), status: 303
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scene as the poster and got over it in the following way.

[application_helper.rb]

```rb
  def parse_from_params(params, anc = nil)
    @tags || = []
    params.each do |row|
      key = if anc
              f, b = anc.split
              f + "\[#{row.first} \]" + b.to_s
            else
              row.first.to_s
            end
      if row.last.is_a?(Hash)
        parse_from_params(row.last, key)
      else
        @tags << hidden_field_tag(key.delete(' '), row.last)
      end
    end
    @tags.reduce(:+)
  end
```

[application_controller.rb]

```rb
  def redirect_keeped_params(url, **options)
    @url = url
    @params = options[:params]
    @method = options[:method]
    render_text = <<-EOS
      <%= form_tag @url, method: @method, id: "redirect_form" do %>
        <%= parse_from_params(@params) %>
        <%= javascript_tag 'document.getElementById("redirect_form").submit()' %>
      <% end %>
    EOS
    render inline: render_text
  end
```

use example...

[posts_controller.rb]

```rb
  def redirect_to_put_preparation
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    params = {}
    params[:post] = {title: params[:title], body: params[:body]}
    # or params = post_params
    redirect_keeped_params(update_post_path(id: post.id), params: params, method: :put) 
  end

  def update_post
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.update(post_params)
    flash[:notice] = "success"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
redirect_to resume_user_url(@user), method: :put
```

I've tried using `method: :post` on link but I haven't tried it with redirect_to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that was another one that I tried with no luck. You're correct it does work with the `link_to` method but that's a bit different.